Swift UI Test - Failed to scroll to visible - popup / fullscreenCover
I'm trying to write some UI tests for my app and i'm using a third party popup view library. Under the hood i see it's using the fullscreenCover view modifier.
My tested class looks something like this
struct FirstTimeView: View {
       var body: some View {

      TabView(selection: $selection) {
        <some views for tab view>
    
       // one of the above views contains a tap taht toggles showLegendView
      }
      .tabViewStyle(PageTabViewStyle())
      .popup(isPresented: self.$showLegendView,
        view: {
          LegendView()
            .cornerRadius(15)
            .accessibilityIdentifier("legend")
        }, customize: popupDefaultCustomisationWithOpaqueAndCloseOnTap)
  }

and my test class looks something like this
app.staticTexts[<id of element to toggle showLegendView>].firstMatch.tap()

If I tap on the popup view wherever, it's dismissed, but i want to tap
on an element inside it so i can also test that it exists there
app.staticTexts["legend"].firstMatch.tap()

if I put a breakpoint on the above line and print the static texts of the app
I get
Find: Target Application 'com.test'
  Output: {
    Application, 0x1023212c0, pid: 40158, label: 'test'
  }
  ↪︎Find: Descendants matching type StaticText
    Output: {
      StaticText, 0x102716de0, {{349.0, 638.7}, {18.0, 14.0}}, identifier: 'legend', label: 'test1'
      StaticText, 0x102717500, {{277.2, 638.7}, {46.7, 14.0}}, identifier: 'legend', label: 'test2'
      StaticText, 0x102717bd0, {{233.2, 638.7}, {19.7, 14.0}}, identifier: 'legend', label: 'test3'

But if i let the code run I get
 t =   397.10s Tap "legend" StaticText
    t =   397.11s     Wait for com.test to idle
    t =   397.12s     Find the "legend" StaticText
    t =   397.14s     Check for interrupting elements affecting "legend" StaticText
    t =   397.21s     Synthesize event
    t =   397.24s         Scroll element to visible
    t =   397.24s         Find the "legend" StaticText
    t =   397.28s         Computed hit point {-1, -1} after scrolling to visible
    t =   397.28s         Failed: Failed to scroll to visible (by AX action) StaticText, {{349.0, 638.7}, {18.0, 14.0}}, identifier: 'legend', label: 'test1', error: Error kAXErrorCannotComplete performing AXAction kAXScrollToVisibleAction on element AX element pid: 40158, elementOrHash.elementID: 105553169980768.46

Not sure why this is happening.
Any ideas? 


Try these methods:

Consider using app.staticTexts["legend"].element(boundBy:0)
See if the isHittable property of the "legend" button is true (If it is not hittable, try to tap using its coordinates)
Try to make the button's container view's "isAccessibilityElement" value set to true

My recommendation is to try accessing an element using its both identifier and label in the following manner if you have numerous elements with the same identifier:
extension XCUIElementQuery {
    func element(id identifier: String, label: String) -> XCUIElement {
        let predicate = NSPredicate(format: "identifier == %@ AND label == %@", identifier, label)
        return element(matching: predicate)
    }
}

Ex: app.staticTexts.element(id: "legend", label: "test1")
Good luck!
